# How do I check if a file exists?

Tags: actionscript-3, ios, ios4, air, flash-cs5

I am using flash cs5 and developing for iOS.  I am using the application storage directory as well.  But, in my code, a file in the storage directory is trying to be read before it is created, and therefore results in errors.  How do I check if the file exists first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [flash docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#exists):

```
import flash.filesystem.*;

var temp:File = File.createTempFile();
trace(temp.exists); // true
temp.deleteFile();
trace(temp.exists); // false
```

Comment: I tried that but I get this error: TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.

Comment: It says that is AIR 1.0, but iphone ios runs on AIR 2.0

Comment: showing some code would help. The runtime version usually indicate which version they were added. they should be compatible AFAIK

Comment: It turns out the real problem is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717937/why-wont-this-code-work