# Why won't this code work?

Tags: actionscript-3

This is a simple actionscript code.  Why won't it work?

```
for (var inc = 1; inc <= 18; inc++)
{
    current = "cb"+inc;
    current.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, storedata);
}
```

Comment: How do you mean "won't work"? What error messages do you get?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have 18 variables: cb1, cb2,.....cb18 and want a quick way to add an event listener to each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably meaning to do is this:

```
for (var inc = 1; inc <= 18; inc++)
{
    this["cb"+inc].addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, storedata);
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: OH this worked!  The problem on my end was I forgot to declare the check boxes on the frame where the event listeners were defined.

Answer (score 0):

`current` in your code seems to be a `String`. You can't add an event listener to a `String`.

Comment: then how should I go about doing this?

Comment: It depends on what is that you want to achieve.

Comment: I have 18 variables: cb1, cb2,.....cb18 and want a quick way to add an event listener to each one